# Where are these <br> tags coming from?

Tags: css, tinymce

I should state that I am not a programmer; I'm trying to solve a problem on a legacy custom web site where the developer is no longer available.

I've got two web sites ("site 1" & "site 2") which use the same custom CMS. The code for one of the site 1 was updated a couple of years ago. I have updated site 2 using copies of common files from site 1. However in site 2 there is unwanted space after the end of each unordered list which does not appear in site 1 - I'm trying to work out where this is coming from.

Using "inspect element" in Firefox, I can see an unwanted br tag after the /ul tag

When I look at the html in the WYSIWYG editor (TinyMCE) the `<br>` tag isn't there, so I assume it is coming from CSS, however the CSS file for site 1 and site 2 are the same.

If I use "inspect" in the Chrome browser and select the unwanted `<br>` tag it says;

```
element.style{
}

"inherited from body"
body {                        master.css ....
font: 12px/1.5em verdana;
color: #444;
}

"inherited from body"
 html {                        user agent stylesheet
     color: -internal-root-color;
 }
```

Are there other tools or methods I could use to work out where these `<br>` tags are coming from?

Comment: CSS doesn’t create tags, so the problem has to be on the server side code that produces the output.

Comment: Sometimes, WYSIWYG editors adds in <br> tags on its own. For example, many convert newlines into <br> tags. I'm not familiar with TinyMCE but I suspect it has to do with how TinyMCE works.

Comment: @Sami Kuhmonen
Okay. Thanks.
So when I see something like this in the CSS it doesn't relate to the br tag?
   ' ul > br{ '

Comment: @Kei  thanks. I will look into TinyMCE. In the config it says " force_br_newlines : false, " but it must be ignoring it for some reason

Comment: It relates to those tags, but it just tells how to render them. It doesn’t alter the structure of the HTML in any way. Only the code running on the server or in the browser (JavaScript, webasm) can alter the actual structure. The most CSS can do to alter things is to append or prepend things with :before and :after and those don’t allow tags